# Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь по заданию с использованием библиотеки jQuery

Tags: javascript

1.
Покрасить имя людей в зависимости от пола в розовый или голубой цвет.

```js
$(document.body).ready(function() {
  // write your code here
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  min-width: 50px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Ім'я</th>
    <th>Стать</th>
    <th>Вік</th>
    <th>Одружений(a)</th>
    <th>Сини</th>
    <th>Доньки</th>
    <th>Дом. тварина</th>
    <th>Зарплата</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Додковська Яна</td>
    <td>Жін.</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>метелик</td>
    <td>334</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Яцуненкова Юлія</td>
    <td>Жін.</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>Ні</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>пацюк</td>
    <td>788</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Білай Олександр</td>
    <td>Чол.</td>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>жаба</td>
    <td>3821</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ярюшенк Дмитро</td>
    <td>Чол.</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>кіт</td>
    <td>822</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Сольвейстров Марк</td>
    <td>Чол.</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>скорпіон</td>
    <td>348</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Вєльковський Олександр</td>
    <td>Чол.</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>метелик</td>
    <td>722</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Каретан Андрій</td>
    <td>Чол.</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>метелик</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Гіроєва Дарина</td>
    <td>Жін.</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>5743</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Тяфф Іван</td>
    <td>Чол.</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>миша</td>
    <td>7843</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: это на каком языке ?

Comment: Сам код написан с помощью HTML

Comment: Стоит задать модификатор, который будет показывать, М или Ж, а потом прогонять циклом по всем модификаторам и выставлять соответствующее значение.

Comment: В том то и проблема, то что я не понимаю до конца, как это записать. Попытки были, но никаких изменений не было.

Comment: я знаю что это html я имею ввиду на каком языке текст внутри ?

Comment: На украинском    языке

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что в таблице все 'Жiн' - это девочки, а 'Чол' - мальчики?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document.body).ready(function() {
  $('tr td:first-child').each(function(i,elem) {
    if ($(this).next().text()=='Жін.') {
      $(this).css("color", "pink");
    }
    if ($(this).next().text()=='Чол.') {
       $(this).css("color", "lightblue");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  min-width: 50px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Ім'я</th>
    <th>Стать</th>
    <th>Вік</th>
    <th>Одружений(a)</th>
    <th>Сини</th>
    <th>Доньки</th>
    <th>Дом. тварина</th>
    <th>Зарплата</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Додковська Яна</td>
    <td>Жін.</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>метелик</td>
    <td>334</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Яцуненкова Юлія</td>
    <td>Жін.</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>Ні</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>пацюк</td>
    <td>788</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Білай Олександр</td>
    <td>Чол.</td>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>жаба</td>
    <td>3821</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ярюшенк Дмитро</td>
    <td>Чол.</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>кіт</td>
    <td>822</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Сольвейстров Марк</td>
    <td>Чол.</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>скорпіон</td>
    <td>348</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Вєльковський Олександр</td>
    <td>Чол.</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>метелик</td>
    <td>722</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Каретан Андрій</td>
    <td>Чол.</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>метелик</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Гіроєва Дарина</td>
    <td>Жін.</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>5743</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Тяфф Іван</td>
    <td>Чол.</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>миша</td>
    <td>7843</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Но по идее задание звучит таким образом, что нужно именно изменить цвет имён в зависимости от пола, а не цвет заднего фона, так скажем.

Comment: @Аня Еськина >_< заменяете слово `background-color` на просто `color`

Comment: Поправил решение.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще вариант с добавлением классов:

Но там от jQuery только ready))

```js
$(document.body).ready(function() {
  const stat = document.getElementsByClassName('stat');
  const color = document.getElementsByClassName('color');
  for(let i = 0; i < stat.length; i++){
    if( stat[i].innerText.match(/Жін/ig) ){
      color[i].style.color = '#ac007c';
    } else if( stat[i].innerText.match(/Чол/ig) ) {
      color[i].style.color = '#045acf';
    }
  }  
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  min-width: 50px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Ім'я</th>
    <th>Стать</th>
    <th>Вік</th>
    <th>Одружений(a)</th>
    <th>Сини</th>
    <th>Доньки</th>
    <th>Дом. тварина</th>
    <th>Зарплата</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color">Додковська Яна</td>
    <td class="stat">Жін.</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>метелик</td>
    <td>334</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color">Яцуненкова Юлія</td>
    <td class="stat">Жін.</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>Ні</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>пацюк</td>
    <td>788</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color">Білай Олександр</td>
    <td class="stat">Чол.</td>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>жаба</td>
    <td>3821</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color">Ярюшенк Дмитро</td>
    <td class="stat">Чол.</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>кіт</td>
    <td>822</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color">Сольвейстров Марк</td>
    <td class="stat">Чол.</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>скорпіон</td>
    <td>348</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color">Вєльковський Олександр</td>
    <td class="stat">Чол.</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>метелик</td>
    <td>722</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color">Каретан Андрій</td>
    <td class="stat">Чол.</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>метелик</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color">Гіроєва Дарина</td>
    <td class="stat">Жін.</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>5743</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color">Тяфф Іван</td>
    <td class="stat">Чол.</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>Так</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>миша</td>
    <td>7843</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

P.s. соседнее решение круче, если речь идет о конкретной разметке. Этот подойдет на случай, если захочется как угодно перетасовать таблицу, но больше не лезть в скрипт)